# Need information on "Salt" parameter of Jmeter

Tags: function, jmeter, sha512

Need to create hash token using SHA-512 Algorithm, So on using `_digest` function of jmeter, I am getting a different token.
What is "salt"? is it same as secret key ?
How to use it?

```
${__digest(SHA-512,{test_test_test},SXF,,)}
```

Answer (score 0):

See documentation of function:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest

Regarding SALT, it is described here:

- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

It’s not a private key, a salt is random data that is used as an additional input to a one-way function that "hashes" data, a password or passphrase. Salts are used to safeguard passwords in storage.